# Apple command line tools vs XCode command line tools?

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools

I downloaded XCode and made sure the XCode command line tools were installed by going to `Preferences` -> `Locations`:

[image]

**The Problem:** When I run `brew upgrade` it throws this error:

```
Error: python@3.10: the bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.
  You can install them, if desired, with:
    xcode-select --install
```

**What I Want To Know:** What's the difference between the XCode command line tools and these Apple command line tools? Do I need to install both?

I'm on OSX 12.3.1, with XCode 13.3.1.

Answer (score 6):

`Apple Command Line Tools` are just another name for `XCode Command Line Tools`.

At your terminal, do:

```
xcode-select --install
```

`Homebrew` should then work.

This [Homebrew issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10714) notes:

> The reason we need the Command Line Tools rather than just Xcode.app is for a few reasons:

> - The CLT contains more SDKs than Xcode - Xcode usually only contains one SDK, and it may be newer than your OS, while the CLT always has a compatible SDK. Having a matching SDK is very important for some formulae.

> - The CLT is in a fixed location /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools while Xcode is not. This matters as some formulae (including Python) bake in paths into files at compile-time - if they pointed to Xcode then it will only work for people who have Xcode installed in the same place.